# $x^{y^z}$: is it $x^{(y^z)}$ or $(x^y)^z$?

Tags: notation, exponentiation, convention

Of the following, *why* is **a** usually considered true, and for what reason other than "tradition" and "more convenient"?

a: ${x}^{y^z} = x^{(y^z)} \neq {(x^y)}^z$

b: ${x}^{y^z} = {(x^y)}^z \neq  x^{(y^z)}$

Edit: I know **a** is correct, but what is the reason for this order of operations?

Comment: @Vadim123's answer is precise. Usually $x^{y^z}$ is taken as $x^{(y^z)}$ because you could just write $x^{yz}$ if you meant option *b*.

Comment: Aka, "tradition" and "more convenient"?

Comment: I guess so. But this is possibly the only reason. Why do you want others? :)

Comment: Your question and vadim's answer have proven fortuitously useful to me, in the field of computing. I just realized that a N-ary exponentiation function that I designed as part of a programming language has in fact the less useful left-associative behavior of: `(expt a b c)` being `(expt (expt a b) c)`, rather than the right associative `(expt a (expt b c))`. Thanks a lot! I may well just fix this.

Comment: ^ Nope! I made it work in the useful way, in fact. I only *documented* it incorrectly as working left-associatively, haha. So the useful thing here is that we found a ref manual bug.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359577/how-to-evaluate-powers-of-powers-i-e-234-in-absence-of-parentheses

Comment: It is not just tradition, it is a convention ! But far lesser known than other conventions like what the square root of $4$ should be , for example.

Answer (score 16):

Choice (b) is pointless since you could instead write $x^{yz}$.

To elaborate, sometimes we mean (a) and sometimes we mean (b).  We already have a way to denote (b), but no other way to denote (a).

Answer (score 1):

As for you title question,$\;$ x^y^z $\;$is ambiguous.

For the question in your post, as formatted:

$$(x^y)^z = x^{(yz)} \neq x^{\large y^z}$$

So option $a$ is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Of course $x^{y^z} = x^{(y^z)} \ne (x^y)^z$. To outline a proof by contradiction - if you suppose that $x^{y^z} = (x^y)^z$, you can take the counter example of $2^{2^3} = 2^8 = 256 \ne (2^2)^3 = 4^3 = 64$.

Comment: But you did not follow the ${x}^{y^{z}} = {(x^y)}^z$ rule in step 2. If you apply it to both sides you *do* get $64 = 64$

Comment: You cannot use the rule in a proof (where you want to show, that such a rule is valid). Here, you only evaluate nested functions. You can also view it like this: Let $exp(a,x)=a^x$. then left side is $exp(x,exp(y,z))$ and right hand side is $exp(exp(x,y),z)$